# is there a method to filter articles by similarity score in an elastic query?

Tags: python, python-3.x, elasticsearch, search, vector

I have searched extensively and, as I am not an expert in elastic queries, I have not found a solution to filter my results. My index contains 450,000 documents. The issue is that when I perform a search, it always returns all 450,000 documents, sorted by relevance. However, upon examining the last results, some of them do not even match my query. Therefore, I am considering the idea of limiting and filtering the results only for the documents with a similarity score greater than 0.5. This way, we can ensure that we will only get relevant results.

```
query["bool"]["should"].append({
"script_score": {
"query": {"match_all": {}},
"script": {
"source": "(1.0 + cosineSimilarity(params['query_vector'], 'vector'))",
"params": {"query_vector": vector_field}
}
}
})
```

how we can do this to filter articles